# SVM's dual problem seems to ignore primal feasibility

Tags: svm, optimization

The primal feasibility is given below:
$$
y_i(w^Tx_i+w_0) \geq 1
$$
and is required when solving primal problem. But when we turn to the dual problem, the inequality becomes $\alpha_i \geq 0$ and we seem to have no way of ensuring that primal feasibility is achieved. How does the computer know that only fulfilling $\alpha_i \geq 0$ will definitely ensure $y_i(w^Tx_i+w_0)\geq1$ as well?

It really confuses me.

Comment: Check out the Geometric Interpretation here: http://www.eng.newcastle.edu.au/eecs/cdsc/books/cce/Slides/Duality.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I read the geometric interpretation and it makes sense, but it does not tell us how we are ensuring that y is always smaller than 0 (as in the slides). We know that y has to be smaller than 0 but from the perspective of dual problem, there is no such constraint as y <= 0, only alpha >= 0. So there is no way of testing if y <= 0 is satisfied solely from the perspective of dual problem... Could you explain how we still happen to ensure that y <=0?